# How to call a method from Jinja template?

Tags: python, template-engine, jinja2

I have a few jinja template file in a path, I want to render them and write them in a file, my problem is their output file name,

Is it possible that define a function in jinja template to return and prepare the template output file name, and call it from python code and retrieve its value?

this is my code:

```
#in here inputPath is jinja templates path
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputPath):
    for file in files:
        fPath = root[len(inputPath) + 1:]
        newPath = (fPath + "/" if fPath else '') + file
        template = env.get_template(newPath)
        oPath = os.path.join(outputPath, fPath)
        try:
            os.makedirs(oPath)
        except:
            pass
        oPath=os.path.join(oPath,file)
        with codecs.open(oPath,'w', "utf-8") as f:
            f.write(template.render(projectname=projectName, mainxmlpath=mainXamlPath))
```

in this code output file name is exactly jinja template file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it,

Template class has module attribute that contains all your template methods and defined variables

for example `template.module.foo()` calls your `foo` macro in the jinja template.